# How do I recover from an awful DMing session?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, new-gm

Protip to anybody out there. If you're running on little to no sleep and an extremely high fever, *don't try to run your game*.

I'm running an online campaign on Roll20, and I - in my deluded, slightly feverish mind - managed to convince myself that I was fine to let the game go forwards, and listening back to the audio, it was a total disaster. I can't even remember half of what happened, only that I somehow skipped a whole bunch of my notes, destroyed the characterisation of a very important NPC **completely** and somehow moved on to something that wasn't supposed to happen for a long time? The game itself wasn't the best work I've ever done - far from it - but it's the fact that I managed to singlehandedly ruin everything that makes me really worried. I particularly worked on the NPC for a while, and he just ended up as some bootleg third cousin of what I was originally going for. The players assure me it went fine, but I'm a new DM and I don't exactly know how to recover.

**What steps can I take to recover the campaign and get it back on track?**

Comment: This reads more like a rant than an answerable question. It's unclear what you're actually trying to ask us.

Comment: [Related] https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37832/43856 - similar question on "session went horribly due to real life issues, how do I proceed?". [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67291/43856) for a similar "DM messed up, how to proceed?" might also help you.

Comment: @MisterB See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Run the next session and see how it goes

People who train horses to accept a saddle used to have an expression: *get back up on the horse that threw you off.*

Your players gave you some positive feedback.  Proceed with the next session of your campaign.  Before that session, clone the NPC as the cousin (or sibling) of the original NPC (who is now a liability to you). This NPC has a different name, but has most or all of the other traits that you assigned to the original NPC.

Have that cloned NPC meet the party at a convenient spot when you are clear headed, and then play on.  *Your players are looking forward to this.*  Chances are, it wasn't that bad of a mistake.